# Cloud Firestore Android codelab

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Looking for help to resolve a build error I am encountering in step #4 Write Data of Cloud Firestore codelab
The compiler seems to be unaware of the Restaurant object that is defined in the app>java>model folder

```
error: cannot find symbol
        CollectionReference restaurants = mFirestore.collection("restaurants");

error: cannot find symbol
            Restaurant restaurant = RestaurantUtil.getRandom(this);
                                    ^
```

Here is the code from the tutorial:

```java
private void onAddItemsClicked() {
    // Get a reference to the restaurants collection
    CollectionReference restaurants = mFirestore.collection("restaurants");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Get a random Restaurant POJO
        Restaurant restaurant = RestaurantUtil.getRandom(this);

        // Add a new document to the restaurants collection
        restaurants.add(restaurant);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any ideas. Here is the link to the tutorial:
[Codelab Firestore](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/#3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example builds before editing it, reproducible at any time:

```
git clone https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-android
cd friendlyeats-android/
mv mock-google-services.json app/google-services.json
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

While `cannot find symbol` means, that you might be missing any of these imports:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.example.fireeats.util.RestaurantUtil;
import com.google.firebase.example.fireeats.model.Restaurant;
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you Martin!

Comment: Also see: IDEA [Auto import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html)